# How to get epoch function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, intervals, epoch

```
select * 
from sample_table scr 
where extract('epoch' from systimestamp - scr.created_date)/60 > :defaultTimeOut
```

This is a postgres query. Trying to convert this query into oracle.

How do I convert epoch in oracle?

TIA.

Comment: What is "epoch" exactly?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson [PostgreSQL `EXTRACT` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html#AEN11159) - for an interval between two times then the "epoch" is the total number of seconds in the interval. If you're just talking about a single timestamp then the epoch time is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually trying to convert an interval (ie the difference between two dates) to a number of seconds. Assuming that `created_date` is of `date` datatype, one method is:

```
select * 
from sample_table
where (sysdate - created_date) * 24 * 60 * 60 > :defaultTimeOut
```

Rationale: in Oracle, substracting two dates returns a decimal number that represents the difference in days. You can multiply that by 24 (hours per day), 60 (minutes per hour) and 60 (seconds per minute) to convert that to a number of seconds, then compare it to the target value.

If `created_date` is of `timestamp` datatype, you can cast it to a `date` first:

```
select * 
from sample_table
where (sysdate - cast(created_date as date)) * 24 * 60 * 60 > :defaultTimeOut
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it is getting error something like this "ORA-01867: the interval is invalid
01867. 00000 -  "the interval is invalid"
*Cause:    The character string you specified is not a valid interval.
*Action:   Please specify a valid interval. "

Comment: @user12333071: this seems to work fine [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07e8cf6a198d98f792cbff8d998a97b6). What is the datatype of column `created_date` in your database?

Comment: The datatype is Timestamp

Comment: @user12333071: I updated my answer with a solution for `timestamp`s